# ReactElement type casting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

This is more of a `Typescript` and `React` question but for full disclosure, I'll mention that I ended up here while trying to create a custom header using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/).

I have a simple `ImageButton` (functional) component, which accepts the following props:

```
export interface ImageButtonProps extends TouchableOpacityProps {
  transparent?: boolean;
}
```

My custom header looks (roughly) like this:

```
export default function Header(props: StackHeaderProps) {
   const options = props.scene.descriptor.options;

   const HeaderRight = options.headerRight as (() => ReactElement<ImageButtonProps>);

   return (<HeaderRight transparent={true}/>); // <-- Typescript complains here
}
```

It's safe to assume that `options.headerRight` will always return an `ImageButton`, which in fact renders just fine. The only issue is that the property `transparent` is always undefined and also Typescript throws the following error:

> TS2322: Type '{ transparent: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.   Property 'transparent' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

So my question is, how can I properly cast a `ReactElement` to my custom component, `ImageButton` and its props?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because the type you casted it to doesn't take any arguments or props.

This means, a function which takes no arguments, returns React.Element:

```
() => ReactElement<ImageButtonProps>
```

You want it to take the props, so you need to type in the props:

```
(props: ImageButtonProps) => ReactElement<any>
```

Or

```
React.ComponentType<ImageButtonProps>
```

Also, TypeScript doesn't support typechecking ReactElement, so there's no need for doing `ReactElement<ImageButtonProps>`.

Also see https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html